# Function that changes the sign of elements in array if the condition between a and b meet

Tags: python, numpy

Change sign of elements in numpy array from a to b.
I tried this.

```
import numpy as np
def do_negative(X, a, b):
    lst = []
    for i in X:
      if (a<i<b):
        lst.append(-i)
      else:
        lst.append(i)
    return X
test = np.array(range(9)).reshape(3,3)
do_negative(test, -1, 3).all()
```

But this returns error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

**Input data:** from -1 to 3.

**Output should be:** np.array([[ 0, -1, -2], [-3,  4,  5], [ 6,  7,  8]])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`X` is 2D numpy array,you have to make it 1D using `flatten()`.Also you returning `X` instead of returning `lst`

```
def do_negative(X, a, b):
  lst = []
  for i in X.flatten():
    if (a < i <= b):
      lst.append(-1*i)
    else:
      lst.append(i)
  return np.array(lst).reshape(3,3)
```

Remove `.all()` when calling the function

```
do_negative(test, -1, 3)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0, -1, -2],
       [-3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `for` loops to do element-wise operations on arrays is not how NumPy is supposed to be used.

This can be done quite easily with a whole-array operation:

```
def do_negative(x, a, b):
    result = x.copy()
    result[(a < x) & (x < b)] *= -1
    return result
```